# Add a counter of the number of objets clicked

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, local-storage

I just made this animation using canvas. Shows a number of bubbles scrolling from top to bottom. Clicking on any bubble starts it moving  top to bottom again.

I plan to add a counter of the number of bubbles clicked/picked with a localStorage  but I have difficulties implementing it.

Comment: In your click event handler you should be able to do this, Create a function that adds  datat to location and call to every time the bubble is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I implemented it.
Each bubble now has `id` property.
Every time you run the script, it puts empty array to `localStorage.clickedBubbles`.
When a bubble is clicked, the array is checked if it contains the `id`. If not, the `id` is pushed to local storage.
Also, each click the count is logged to console.

```js
const INITIALIZATION = 100;
const STEP1 = 200;
const BUBBLES = 10;
const SPEED = 10;
let counter = 0;

localStorage.setItem("clickedBubbles", "[]");

function Bubble(x, y, radio) {
  this.id = counter++;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radio = radio;
  this.color = "blue";
  this.speed = 5;

  this.getId = function () {
    return this.id;
  };
  this.getX = function () {
    return this.x;
  };
  this.getY = function () {
    return this.y;
  };
  this.getRadio = function () {
    return this.radio;
  };
  this.getColor = function () {
    return this.color;
  };
  this.getspeed = function () {
    return this.speed;
  };
  this.setX = function (x) {
    this.x = x;
  };
  this.setY = function (y) {
    this.y = y;
  };
  this.setRadio = function (radio) {
    this.radio = radio;
  };
  this.setColor = function (color) {
    this.color = color;
  };
  this.setSpeed = function (speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  };
  this.draw = function (ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radio, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
      this.x + this.radio / 3,
      this.y - this.radio / 3,
      this.radio / 4,
      0,
      Math.PI * 2,
      true
    );
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  };

  this.coordinates = function (x, y) {
    var ax = this.getX() - this.getRadio();
    var ay = this.getY() - this.getRadio();
    return (
      x >= ax &&
      x <= ax + 2 * this.getRadio() &&
      y >= ay &&
      y <= ay + 2 * this.getRadio()
    );
  };
}

function animationBubbles() {
  var bubbles = [];
  var arrayColors;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var status = INITIALIZATION;
  var app = this;

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  this.click = function (e) {
    var x = e.x || e.pageX || e.clientX;
    var y = e.y || e.clientY || e.pageY;
    const clickedArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clickedBubbles"));

    for (var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
      var aux = bubbles[i];
      if (aux.coordinates(x, y)) {
        if (!clickedArr.includes(aux.getId())) {
          clickedArr.push(aux.getId());
          localStorage.setItem("clickedBubbles", JSON.stringify(clickedArr));
        }
        aux.setY(0);
        break;
      }
    }

    console.log("Clicked count: " + clickedArr.length);
  };

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.click, false);

  this.realizeAnimation = function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
      var aux = bubbles[i];
      if (aux.getY() < canvas.height) {
        aux.setY(aux.getY() + aux.getspeed());
      } else {
        aux.setY(0);
        aux.setColor(arrayColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
      }
      aux.draw(ctx);
    }
    setTimeout(app.realizeAnimation, 100);
  };

  this.createBubbles = function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= BUBBLES; i++) {
      var burbuja = new Bubble(
        canvas.width * (i / BUBBLES),
        0,
        this.generateRandom(Math.floor(canvas.width / 20))
      );
      burbuja.setSpeed(SPEED);
      burbuja.setColor(arrayColors[this.generateRandom(4)]);
      bubbles.push(burbuja);
    }
  };

  this.generateRandom = function (num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
  };

  this.initColor = function () {
    arrayColors[0] = "#C923C9";
    arrayColors[1] = "#FAEF20";
    arrayColors[2] = "#20ECFA";
    arrayColors[3] = "#FA209C";
  };

  this.machineStates = function () {
    if (status === INITIALIZATION) {
      arrayColors = [];
      this.initColor();
      this.createBubbles();
      status = STEP1;
      setTimeout(app.machineStates, 100);
    } else {
      app.realizeAnimation();
    }
  };

  this.machineStates();
}
new animationBubbles();
```

Comment: It has been quite helpful, I understood quite well how you have achieved it, I will continue to improve it, so that the score appears on the screen.